# How to measure the time to create a record in the UI?

Tags: custom-button, case

I need to measure the time it takes since the user clicks on the "New" button until the record is saved.  I only need to measure this for cases and on the standard page layout in the Salesforce Console.

I was thinking of doing this by passing the time **{!now()}** in the URL of a custom button that would replace the standard new button, on the URL the **{!now()}** value should be assigned to a custom field (Date/Time) and upon saving the record a formula would calculate then the difference between the Created Date/Time and the custom field I populated.

The problem with this approach is that it requires the custom field to be visible on the page layout which not only is not needed in the page but could also be modified by the user.

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Have you considered putting Google Analytics into a homepage component in your CRM system? You should then be able to look at visits to the `salesforce.com/500/e` page.

Comment: @MarkKeats Thanks, I will look into that, have you tried done that before?

Comment: I haven't used it in Salesforce before, but I have used it for similar reasons in other web applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Apex-Lang Utils Library](http://code.google.com/p/apex-lang/) has a StopWatch.cls which has a variety of time related methods including methods for getting the time of running states, time splits and more. The utilities are also available on Git someplace, but the Google link was the one I had at hand. I'd recommend using this class to record your method.

There are several ways of approaching implementing the class. Even though this is a standard page, you could replace it with a custom one that uses an extension on the controller which implements this class when new records are created. There's a free utility in the App Exchange called [Layout Page](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZkUEAU) that will usually do a good job of converting a Standard Page into a Standard VisualForce Page. I've used it several times with success.

I'd think you'd know how to do the rest in terms of getting your start and finish times, then recording the elapsed time to a record upon save.

With this method, I'd think you'd be able to save it to custom object rather than to the new record itself. As I don't know what your objectives are, whether that's a benefit or not, I couldn't say.

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately rebuilding the standard page layout is not an option for us.

Comment: Not a prob Pepe. Its often difficult to provide answers to questions like this as one never knows exactly all of the constraints someone has to work with. It at least helps us to think about how we'd approach solving the problem ourselves; making it a useful exercise. We then usually learn something new from others when we see their solutions too. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I have created frameworks to do this in the past to report on Apex performance. However this only shows you the Server Side time.

http://corycowgill.blogspot.com/2014/03/instrument-your-apex-code-diy.html

You can use this blog post which shows you how to use Boomerang to get responses all the way through the UI.

http://www.salesforcehacker.com/2014/06/capturing-user-information-on.html

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the field for your users and use *without sharing* on your class so that the Apex code can edit the otherwise inaccessible field. Have a look at: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm

Also, keep in mind that Salesforce datetime measures only as accurately as seconds. You may want to consider saving the return value of System.currentTimeMillis() instead. Have a look at:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_currentTimeMillis